# Output Empty/Blank Line/Separation Line to Text file

Tags: file, batch-file, export, blank-line

I am data mining a log file and exporting information successfully.  What I am looking to do is put a few blank, empty, or some kind of line separator between each export within the data mining criteria the script finds.  I currently have:

```
  SET "_LogFile=C:\Test.log"
  SET "_ResultFile=OutPut.txt"
  SET "_MatchString_Begin=<Line Text="***********TEST************"
  SET "_MatchString_End=</Report>"
  SET "_Line#_Begin="
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT/B
)
:Main
CLS
  IF EXIST "%_ResultFile%" (
    DEL /F /Q "%_ResultFile%"
  )
  COLOR 0F
  ECHO.&ECHO.===== Processing =====&ECHO.
  FOR /F "Delims=[]" %%# IN ('
    Find /N "%_MatchString_Begin:"=""%" "%_LogFile%" ^| FIND "["
  ') DO (
    ECHO. Found Match On Line %%#
    SET /A "_Line#_Begin=%%#-1"
    CALL :Output
  )
  COLOR 20
  ECHO.&ECHO.===== Completed! =====

FOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%I in ('type "%_ResultFile%" ^& ^> "%_ResultFile%" rem/') do (
    >> "%_ResultFile%" echo(%%I
)

REN %_ResultFile% Trythis.csv

START TryThis.csv

GOTO :EOF

:Output
  FOR /F "SKIP=%_Line#_Begin% Tokens=* usebackq" %%_ IN (
    "%_LogFile%"
  ) DO (
    ECHO(%%_
    ECHO("%%_" | FIND /I "%_MatchString_End%" >NUL&&(
      GOTO :EOF
    )
  )>>"%_ResultFile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

In my export I get:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
CCC
CCC
CCC
```

Would be nice to see:

```
 AAA
 AAA
 AAA
 ---
 BBB
 BBB
 BBB
 ---
 CCC
 CCC
 CCC
```

A is one block that is exported, B is another Block Exported, C is another block exported.  They currently all merge line after line.  Would be nice to a separator in between each block exported.

Any suggestions would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: echo.>>"%_ResultFile%"

Comment: Have tried this, however, does not work.  Maybe not putting in the correct position?  I have updated preliminary scripting to original post.

Comment: Where do you want the blank lines to be?

Comment: In between each data set found.  If you see my SET commands - SET "_MatchString_Begin=<Line Text="**TEST**"
 SET "_MatchString_End=</Report>"
After it finds the "</Report>" if I can put a blank/empty line or 2 or some sort of separator in between.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put it in the :output section like this:

```
:Output
FOR /F "SKIP=%_Line#_Begin% Tokens=* usebackq" %%_ IN ("C:\Test.log") DO (
   ECHO(%%_
   ECHO("%%_" | FIND /I "%_MatchString_End%" >NUL&&ECHO(&&(GOTO :EOF)
)>>"%_ResultFile%"
```

Your full code, changing a bunch of things the way I would more likely do them.  I know Mofi really dislikes `echo.` -- but I work with computers that I have control of and I do not worry about the tiny chance of problems.  If you care about it, you can replace all of the `echo.` with `echo/`

```
SET "_MatchString_Begin=<Line Text="**TEST**"
SET "_MatchString_End=</Report>"
SET "_Line#_Begin="   

ECHO.
ECHO ===== Processing =====
ECHO.
FOR /F "Delims=[]" %%a IN ('Find /N "%_MatchString_Begin:"=""%" "C:\Test.log" ^| FIND "["') DO (
   ECHO Found Match On Line %%a>>"%_ResultFile%"
   SET /A "_Line#_Begin=%%a-1"
   rem CALL :Output   I do not understand what this line is doing here.
   rem :Output I also do not understand what this line is doing here.
   FOR /F "SKIP=%_Line#_Begin% Tokens=* usebackq" %%b IN ("C:\Test.log") DO (
      ECHO.%%b>>"%_ResultFile%"
      rem the next line is the blank line if you want it after every line in test.log
      ECHO.>>"%_ResultFile%"
      rem the next line also adds a blank line after finding the ending matching string
      ECHO.%%b^| FIND /I "%_MatchString_End%" >NUL && (
         rem what to do when we match the end string
         rem blank line here if this is where you want it
         echo.>>"%_ResultFile%"
         GOTO :EOF
      )
   )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I find that redirecting every line you want into the output file is more understandable than redirecting the entire output of a `for` statement to a file.  It does lead to repeated code -- but you have the flexibility of redirecting to multiple files or just echoing to the console.

Also, I still don't think this is your actual code.  I had to add parentheses here and there.  Perhaps the :output section was supposed to be *outside* the initial `for` loop ??

Here's what I think your code is actually supposed to be:

```
SET "_MatchString_Begin=<Line Text="**TEST**"
SET "_MatchString_End=</Report>"
SET "_Line#_Begin="   

ECHO.
ECHO ===== Processing =====
ECHO.
FOR /F "Delims=[]" %%a IN ('Find /N "%_MatchString_Begin:"=""%" "C:\Test.log" ^| FIND "["') DO (
   ECHO Found Match On Line %%a
   SET /A "_Line#_Begin=%%a-1"
   CALL :Output
   echo.>>"%_ResultFile%"
)
goto :eof

:Output
FOR /F "SKIP=%_Line#_Begin% Tokens=* usebackq" %%b IN ("C:\Test.log") DO (
   ECHO.%%b>>"%_ResultFile%"
   ECHO.%%b| FIND "%_MatchString_End%" >NUL && GOTO :EOF
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Ultimately though, I wouldn't loop through the file over and over again like that.  This is what I'd do:
**UNTESTED**  Could easily be minor errors like missing a `^`.

```
@echo off
SET "_MatchString_Begin=<Line Text="**TEST**"
SET "_MatchString_End=</Report>"
SET "_Line#_Begin="

:: output_flag is used to decide if the lines should be output or not
SET "output_flag=N"
cls

ECHO.
ECHO ===== Processing =====
ECHO.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN ("C:\Test.log") DO (
   ECHO.%%a|find "%_MatchString_Begin:"=""%"  && set "output_flag=Y"
   if "!output_flag!"=="Y" echo.%%a>>"%_ResultFile%"
   echo.%%a|find "%_MatchString_End%" >nul &&echo.>>"%_ResultFile%"&&set "output_flag=N"
)
```

Comment: In my effort to simplify things, believe I have made things much more complicated than they need to be.  I have updated my FULL code, which works great, just needs the separator.  The code I tried from you breaks the full and does not complete what I am looking for unfortunately.  Hope the FULL code helps!

Comment: @avery_larry: I agree, chances for problems are small (but why take the risk), but `echo.` does look for a file on the disk (searches current workfolder and the complete `%path%`), so `echo/` is surely much faster. I know, batch isn't about speed, but in a tight loop, that additional time might matter.

Comment: `echo/` is so ugly to me I don't know that I'll ever change.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
echo/>>"%_ResultFile%"
```

immediately after this line:

```
CALL :Output
```

inside the `for` loop.

But I'm not sure what this `for` loop even does, so it could mess it up:

```
FOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%I in ('type "%_ResultFile%" ^& ^> "%_ResultFile%" rem/') do (
    >> "%_ResultFile%" echo(%%I
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this suggested line of code does not work successfully either.  This was one of the original locations I tried with no success. This line of code 
`
FOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%I in ('type "%_ResultFile%" ^& ^> "%_ResultFile%" rem/') do (
    >> "%_ResultFile%" echo(%%I
)
`
Simply cleans up garbage characters within the output I don't want or need.

Comment: @T-Diddy There is no way the output file doesn't have blank lines in it somewhere -- unless those blank lines are removed later.   Troubleshoot by not using that final for loop.